# How can I do an update on all my entries?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to update all my emails entries in my table USER but I don't want how to do this. I mean let's suppose my table is like this :

```
id  email           name
1   peter@peter.fr  Peter
2   david@david.fr  David
3   paul@paul.fr    Paul
```

I would like to update my email entries such as

```
id  email           name
1   peter1@peter.fr  Peter
2   peter2@peter.fr  David
3   peter3@peter.fr    Paul
```

Is it possible ?

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE "user"
SET email = format('peter%s@peter.fr', id);
```